# Connecting various devices to Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, keypad

I need to connect the following devices to an Arduino UNO board. The problem is that I run out of pins to be able to connect them all. Is there any way to do it?

- ultrasonic sensor
- yellow led
- green led
- red led
- buzzer
- keypad 4x4

I'm doing the project in Tinkercad

In the picture below I tried to do it, but I am missing 2 pins for the ultrasonic sensor trig and echo

[image]

Comment: You can use the analog pins as digital input / output pins.

Comment: Another option would be one of these: https://www.instructables.com/PCF8574-GPIO-Extender-With-Arduino-and-NodeMCU/

Answer (score 3):

As cguck70 already stated in the comments: The pins A0 to A5 can be analog input pins, but they can also be normal digital input/output pins. You can use them to your liking, just like any other digital input/output.

So just connect two of these pins to your ultrasonic sensor and use the pin names `A0`, `A1` and so on in your code.